# creating custom legend / guide for alpha level

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to plot gene expression levels. Essentially for each gene I draw a "pyplot.arrow" and color it by alpha=expression_level. expression levels are normalized to values between 0 and 1.
Now I want to create a legend based on the alpha, which shows what level of alpha corresponds to what expression level.

Here is a sample code for the creating the plot for a few genes:

```py
genes = pd.DataFrame({'start': [52285155, 52391508, 52776238], 'end': [52390609, 52405893, 52782964], 'name': ['ITGA2', 'MOCS2', 'FST'], 'expression': [8.48, 12.3, 3.83], 'strand' : ['+', '-', '+']})
genes = genes.sort_values(by = ["start"])
plt.xlim(genes['start'].min()- 5000, genes['end'].max() + 5000)

#this is to assign different y values so I don't draw them on top of each other. Not important for this question.
gene_count = genes.shape[0]
heights = max(1 / gene_count, 0.33)
height_start = heights / 2
heights = list(np.arange(height_start, height_start + heights * gene_count, heights) % 1)
genes['y'] = heights

# this is to normalize expression values to [0-1]
colors = genes["expression"]
genes["expression_color"] = (colors - colors.min())/(colors.max()-colors.min())  

genes["width"] = genes["end"] - genes["start"]
for g in range(genes.shape[0]):
        g = genes.iloc[g]
        if g.strand == "+":
            plt.arrow(g.start, g.y, g.width, 0, length_includes_head = True, width = 0.1, head_width = 0.2, head_length = g.width*0.05, alpha = g.expression_color)
        else:
            plt.arrow(g.end, g.y, -g.width, 0, length_includes_head = True, width = 0.1, head_width = 0.2, head_length = g.width*0.05, alpha = g.expression_color)
        plt.text(x = (g.start + g.end)/2, y = g.y, s = g["name"], size = 16, horizontalalignment='center')
```

I'd like to add a small color guide like a transparency legend that shows alpha = 0 corresponds to 3.83 (min expression before scaling), alpha = 1 corresponds to 12.3 (max expression before scaling).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I ended up doing this if anyone in the future has a similar problem.

Get the axes you are working on using plt.gca() then create another axes that will be plotted inside it using axes.inset_axes().
instead of using alpha to color different expression values, use a matplotlib colormap like "YlOrRd" (I have set alphas to 0.8 so that there is transparency if there are overlaps between gene locations and/or the legend.
I have also replaced my previous normalization to [0,1] by the matplotlib.colors.Normalize function (you can use matplotlib.colors.LogNorm too).

```py
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

def add_legend(ax, genes):
    ax.patch.set_alpha(0.5)
    exp_max = genes["log10exp"].max()
    exp_min = genes["log10exp"].min()
    print(exp_max, exp_min)
    gradient = np.linspace(exp_min, exp_max, 256)
    gradient = gradient.reshape(1,256)
    ax.imshow(gradient, aspect='auto', cmap="YlOrRd", alpha = 0.8)
    #ax.set_xticks([])
    ax.set_xticks([0, 128, 256])
    ax.set_xticklabels(["{:0.2f}".format(float(exp_min)), "{:0.2f}".format(exp_max/2), "{:0.2f}".format(exp_max)])
    ax.tick_params(axis="x",direction="in", pad=-10)
    #ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('top')
    ax.set_yticks([])
    ax.set_xlabel("log10(expression+1)")

genes = pd.DataFrame({'start': [52285155, 52391508, 52776238], 'end': [52390609, 52405893, 52782964], 'name': ['ITGA2', 'MOCS2', 'FST'], 'expression': [8.48, 78.3, 3.83], 'strand' : ['+', '-', '+']})
genes = genes.sort_values(by = ["start"])
plt.xlim(genes['start'].min()- 5000, genes['end'].max() + 5000)
#this is to assign different y values so I don't draw them on top of each other. Not important for this question.
gene_count = genes.shape[0]
heights = max(1 / gene_count, 0.33)
height_start = heights / 2
heights = list(np.arange(height_start, height_start + heights * gene_count, heights) % 1)
genes['y'] = heights
cmap = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap('YlOrRd')

# this is to normalize expression values to [0-1]
genes['log10exp'] = np.log10(genes["expression"] + 1)
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=colors.min(), vmax=colors.max())
genes["expression_color"] = genes.log10exp.apply(norm)


genes["width"] = genes["end"] - genes["start"]
for g in range(genes.shape[0]):
        g = genes.iloc[g]
        if g.strand == "+":
            plt.arrow(g.start, g.y, g.width, 0, length_includes_head = True, width = 0.1, head_width = 0.2, head_length = g.width*0.05, color = cmap(g.expression_color), alpha = 0.8)
        else:
            plt.arrow(g.end, g.y, -g.width, 0, length_includes_head = True, width = 0.1, head_width = 0.2, head_length = g.width*0.05, color = cmap(g.expression_color), alpha = 0.8)
        plt.text(x = (g.start + g.end)/2, y = g.y, s = g["name"], size = 16, horizontalalignment='center')   
ax = plt.gca()
ax2 = ax.inset_axes([0.88,0.88,0.1,0.1])
add_legend(ax2, genes)
```

An example output is here:
[image]